# Angular places colon outside of HTML element

Tags: angular

Angular (9.1.1) moves my colon always outside of the element and I can't select it in DOM because of that.

Template :

```
<div title>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <b class="myClass">{{ log.topic }} : </b> 
</div>
```

In DOM:

[image]

The colon is never included in the string. I tried:

- concatenating: `{{ log.topic + ':' }}`
- encoding: `.. {{log.topic }} &#58; </b>`

the outcome was always the same. What can be done to put the colon in the same element with the "options" string ?

Comment: The DOM shows a `<b>` in a `<p>` whereas the code shows a `<b>` in a `<div>`. Are you sure that you are looking at the right place ?

Comment: you were right indeed, although chrome's element selector pointed me to that misleading element. thanks for your help.